# Object or function not permitted within signal handlers

Tags: c++, signals, std

I'm looking for a definition of *"object or function not permitted within signal handler"*. It's used in sec. 3.6.3/4 of N3797:

> If there is a use of a standard library **object or function not**
>   **permitted within signal handlers** (18.10) that does not happen before
>   (1.10) completion of destruction of objects with static storage
>   duration and execution of std::atexit registered functions (18.5), the
>   program has undefined behavior.

In general I would like to find an example for this UB rule.

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2204014

Comment: @BЈовић Thanks for that reference. But is there normative reference in the Standard?

Comment: I don't know what "normative reference" is, but you wrote in the question what the standard tells.

Comment: @BЈовић Of course, I'm looking for this reference in the c++ standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In quoted draft in 18.10/9:

> The common subset of the C and C++ languages consists of all declarations, definitions, and expressions that may appear in a well formed C++ program and also in a conforming C program. A POF (“plain old function”) is a function that uses only features from this common
>   subset, and that does not directly or indirectly use any function that
>   is not a POF, except that it may use functions defined in Clause 29
>   that are not member functions. All signal handlers shall have C
>   linkage. A POF that could be used as a signal handler in a conforming
>   C program does not produce undefined behavior when used as a signal
>   handler in a C++ program. The behavior of any other function used as a signal handler in a C++ program is implementation-defined.<sup>228</sup>

Permitted in signal handlers are functions that are both valid in C++ and C. Additionally you can use atomic non-member functions (Clause 29). Implementations may allow other functions to work, but note that:

> 228) In particular, a signal handler using exception handling is very
>   likely to have problems. Also, invoking std::exit may cause
>   destruction of objects, including those of the standard library
>   implementation, which, in general, yields undefined behavior in a
>   signal handler (see 1.9).

According to rule quoted by you, in most cases, leaving some thread running after `main` is finished and all static variables are destroyed will cause UB. It is only allowed if the function is signal-safe and doesn't use standard library.

Comment: Clear answer! Thanks.